# Rolling year to date average in R

Tags: r, zoo, moving-average

How would I compute the (financial) year to date average of a data set in R?

My data is of the form:

```
library(zoo)
DF=data.frame(Day=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-03-01"), as.POSIXct("2017-06-07"),"day"),Value=rnorm(98,1,2))
DF$`5day_rolling`=rollmean(DF$Value,5,fill=NA,align="left")

DF$Financial_yr=as.numeric(format(DF$Day, "%Y")) + (format(DF$Day, "%m") >= "04")
```

Where I have thus far calculated the 5 day rolling mean. I have added a financial year column, which is to be used for the year to date average. So, what i'd like, is an additional column which starts by being equal to the first value of the first day of FY1, the second value being an average of the first 2 days, third being average of three etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ave` to group by financial year and then use `cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)` to calculate the year-to-date average.  No packages are used.

```
cumavg <- function(x) cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)
transform(DF, avg_ytd = ave(Value, Financial_yr, FUN = cumavg))
```